# Rounding is not working as expected in c sharp

Tags: c#

Rounding is not working as expected:

for this value 403.1245 i am expecting result 403.13 after rounding.

I have try this logic but not find this value : 403.13

> Math.Round(403.125);
>
> 403
>
> Math.Round(403.125,2)
>
> 403.12
>
> Math.Round(403.135, 2)
>
> 403.14
>
> Math.Round(403.145, 2)
>
> 403.14
>
> Math.Round(403.115, 2)
>
> 403.12
>
> Math.Round(403.125, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
>
> 403.12
>
> Math.Round(403.125, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.13
>
> Math.Round(403.115, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.12
>
> Math.Round(403.114, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.11
>
> Math.Round(403.1145, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.11
>
> Math.Round(403.1145, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.115
>
> Math.Round(403.1145, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
>
> 403.11
>
> 403.115.ToString("0.00")
>
> "403.12"
>
> 403.1145.ToString("0.00")
>
> "403.11"
>
> 403.1145.ToString("0.000")
>
> "403.115"
>
> 403.1145.ToString("0.01")
>
> "403.11"
>
> 403.1245.ToString("0.01")
>
> "403.11"
>
> string str = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 403.1245M);
>
> str
>
> "403.12"

Comment: 403.1245 i am expecting result 403.13, on what basis?

Comment: @viveknuna if 403.1245 i am rounding this value the expected result i want 403.13 in c#

Comment: That's not the correct result of rounding, though. The correct result of rounding is 403.12, which is exactly what you get. Did you intend to use some kind of ceiling function instead?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica checked below answer it's sorted out in .net core but not solved in .net framework 4.7

Comment: "Sorted out" and "not solved" kinda imply you think it's a bug.. but you should really tag the runtime you use, as just saying c# will give all kinds of responses

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in **.Net Core**

```cs
Math.Round(403.1245, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity);
```

**Result :**  *403.13*

Comment: Yes it's working in .net core but not in .net Framework 4.7.

Comment: I was gonna say; it's not an option in .net std

Comment: Hmmm, this should be `403.12` as the rounding part is '...45' it is NOT a halfway value. When the value was `403.125` I would expect `403.13` - this way `ToPositiveInfinity` seems to be acting like the `Ceiling` method, which will round any value greater than `403.12` and less than `403.13` up to `403.13`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need this on .NET framework:

```
Math.Round(Math.Round(403.1245, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

I'm also not really clear on whether you're just trying to solve some strange edge case or whether you're trying to make it that "every number of the form m.noxx shall round to m.n(o+1)" - in which case you might need to just roll your own, possibly multiplying by 100, rounding up (like with Math.Ceil), dividing by 100 again etc

Answer (score 1):

Expected value is not possible by using the default `Math.Round()` method in .Net Framework 4.7.2, you have to write your custom extension method for that.

`Math.Round` provide you the following ways.

```
double d = Math.Round(403.1245, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //403.125
double d = Math.Round(403.1245, 3); //403.124
```

But in .Net Core 3 you can get this .

```
double d = Math.Round(403.1245, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity);
```